# Unable to set Filter Compliance property in Geoserver Datastore using REST api

Tags: java, rest, geoserver

i'm trying to create from Geoserver Rest API a datastore (in particular a Web Feature Server store) with this request body

```
{
    "dataStore": {
        "name": "wfsRestApi",
        "description": "Description web feature service creatoin from api",
        "type": "Web Feature Server (NG)",
        "enabled": true,
        "connectionParameters": {
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL": "https://gs-stable.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows",
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:USERNAME": "",
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:PASSWORD": "",
            // "WFSDataStoreFactory:OUTPUTFORMAT": 80,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:ENCODING": "UTF-8",
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:TIMEOUT": 30000,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:USE_HTTP_CONNECTION_POOLING": true,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:MAX_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE": 6,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:AXIS_ORDER": "Compliant",
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:AXIS_ORDER_FILTER": "Compliant",
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:TRY_GZIP": true,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:BUFFER_SIZE": 10,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:WFS_STRATEGY": "auto",
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:FILTER_COMPLIANCE": 0,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:MAXFEATURES": 0,
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:GML_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL": 0
        },
        "_default": false
    }
}
```

Everything works fine (i receive the 201 created status code) but when i access to the geoserver web application and go to the detail page of the store just created, i see that the Filter Compliace property is empty (see image below)

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried to reverse engineering the geoserver source code but i'm still figure it out. 
 Another request body that i've used (with the same result of the previous) is the sequent

```
{
    "dataStore": {
        "name": "wfs",
        "description": "Description web feature service creatoin from api",
        "type": "Web Feature Server (NG)",
        "enabled": true,
        "connectionParameters": {
            "entry": [
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL",
                    "value": "https://gs-stable.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows"
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:USERNAME",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:PASSWORD",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:FILTER_COMPLIANCE",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:MAXFEATURES",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:WFS_STRATEGY",
                    "value": "auto"
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:GML_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:AXIS_ORDER",
                    "value": "Compliant"
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:AXIS_ORDER_FILTER",
                    "value": "Compliant"
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:TIMEOUT",
                    "value": 30000
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:BUFFER_SIZE",
                    "value": 10
                },
                {
                    "key": "WFSDataStoreFactory:MAX_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE",
                    "value": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        "_default": false
    }
}
```

Is anyone experiencing the same behavior? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The usual solution is to set the parameter you want in the GUI and then make a GET request to see how it is encoded and modify that response as a template.

Comment: @IanTurton I've tried as you said and got the template but doesn't working either

Comment: The next thing to try is using XML rather than JSON, and of that fails then raise a bug and submit a PR

Comment: @IanTurton With XML i have the same result